# RKHS of a Brownian Bridge Covariance

Tags: probability

The RKHS of a standard Brownian motion covariance ($s \wedge t$) is $\{f \in AC, f(0)=0, f' \in L^{1}[0,1]\}$, with inner product $<f,g>H_{k} = \int f'g'$.

How would I extend this to find the RKHS of the standard Brownian bridge $s \wedge t - st$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RKHS of a standard Brownian bridge $s\wedge t-st$ is
$$
f\in AC, f(0)=f(1)=0, and f^\prime\in L_2([0,1])
$$
with the same inner product as above.

Remark: the RKHS to a standard Brownian motion covariance $s\wedge t$ should be 
$$
f\in AC, f(0)=f(1)=0, and f^\prime\in L_2([0,1])
$$
with inner product ...

Moreover, the L2 condition is imposed to ensure the norm is finite.

Specifically, we need to check two conditions: 1) $K(t,x)\in H$, which is trivial. $K(t,0)=K(t,1)=0$ and $K(t,x)$ is $(1-t)\vee t-$ Lipschitz, and thus absolutely continuous.

2) Reproducing property, that is, $\langle f, K(t,\cdot)\rangle_H=f(t)$ for any $f\in H$.By the formula of $K(t,x)=t\wedge x-t x$, we get that $K^\prime(t,x)=(1-t), \forall x\in[0,t]$ and $K^\prime(t,x)=-t,\forall x\in[t,1]$. Henceforth,

$$
\langle f, K(t,\cdot)\rangle=\int_0^t(1-t)f^\prime(x)dx+\int_t^1(-t)f^\prime(x)dx=(1-t)f(t)-t[f(1)-f(t)]=f(t)
$$

Then, we can invoke the uniqueness theorem to conclude the proof.